# I have a KMS/MAC key for Excel 2010, where can I download the media?

Tags: licensing, microsoft-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I need to get the stand alone version of Excel 2010 installed on a server. I have the KMS/MAC key for it but I can't find the media to download anywhere. All I can find is the full office versions and the key will not work with them.

I have a technet account (looking for login info for the account now) I'm guessing it will be on there but if anyone else knows a legit spot to download it from, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: KMS (aka VL) keys are not the same as MAK, OEM, or Retails keys. MS has 4 separate key types, though the MAK and Retail work essentially the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [licensing.microsoft.com](http://licensing.microsoft.com).

You'll have to set up a profile, with your agreement number. If there's an existing account tied to it, you'll have to have that person add you with download privilege. You should be able to find just about anything Microsoft < 5 years old.

Answer (score 2):

That KMS key is meant to be installed on the KMS host in the domain, its not meant to be plugged in during setup for a single client. You need to use a MAK key for Office or an individual application unless you really intend to use KMS to activate multiple copies of Excel out there.

Comment: Sorry looking back I have both a MAK and KMS